# Infinispan Soft Index File Store issue

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search, infinispan

Indexing around 180,000,000 records in a jgroups autoelection cluster, everythings works fine(I index and query the data and the results seems to valid) but in every startup and shutdown I get these kind of errors. Is it something due to experimental mode that I have to be concerned about?

This is what I get on startup:

```
2018-01-16 08:46:43,315 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.Index]
(BCS-IndexUpdater-2) Error in indexer thread:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

This is what I get on shutdown:

> 8-01-16 09:22:12,538 INFO  [org.hibernate.search.backend.jgroups.impl.DispatchMessageSender] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HSEARCH200017: Disconnecting and closing JGroups Channel to cluster 'Hibernate Search Cluster'
>
> 2018-01-16 09:22:12,579 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.Index]
>   (BCS-IndexUpdater-0) Error in indexer thread:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
>           at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:546)
>           at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.putLong(HeapByteBuffer.java:432)
>           at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.Index$Segment.shutdown(Index.java:368)
>           at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.Index$Segment.run(Index.java:265)
>
> 2018-01-16 09:22:12,583 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.Index]
>   (BCS-IndexUpdater-2) Error in indexer thread:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
>           at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:546)
>           at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.putLong(HeapByteBuffer.java:432)
>           at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.Index$Segment.shutdown(Index.java:368)
>           at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.Index$Segment.run(Index.java:265)

My index is in two fields and none of these are type Long, in case the error is about the type of index data:

```
@Id
@Type(type="objectid")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.NO, norms=Norms.NO)
@DateBridge(resolution = Resolution.SECOND)
private Date dateCreated;

@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.NO, norms=Norms.NO)
private String eventType;

@Embedded
private Location location;
@Embedded
private EventStatus status;
```

Anybody had the same issue before or any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: looks like a bug in Infinispan's sifs. Could you mention the versions used please?

Comment: Infinispan 8.2.7, Hibernate Search 5.6.1, Hibernate OGM 5.1. This combo worked well so far for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Sanne Should I report it somewhere?

Comment: It'd be interesting to see if the issue is still present in latest Infinispan version, which is 9.1.4.Final. However, I don't see any stable OGM releases that use that, maybe you can try with the development OGM 5.2 version just in case? If issue still present, place to report it in would be [here](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/ISPN/summary)

Comment: @GalderZamarreno I tried too but I have troubles in the build with OGM 5.2, Infinispan 9.1.4.Final. I keep getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport even if the class is there and everything was cleaned and rebuilt. I guess it has to do with the versions cause It was difficult to find a working combination between hibernate search, ogm, infinispan. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, please file a [JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/).

However the good news is that it is not harmful to your data; the index is dispensable by design. The shutdown procedure where the bug pops out is there just to speed up restarts, writing some in-memory data and magic word that tells that the index can be used after restart. If this magic word isn't there the cache store deletes the file and starts anew, reading all the records and rebuilding the index.